# How do I reset iPhone if hard reset (power + home) won't work

Tags: iphone, performance

I have an iPhone that is frozen while browsing with Safari (it happens all the time). I am aware that holding down the power button with the home button for 10 seconds is supposed to reset the phone. It does not. I have held down for 60 sec or longer at least 10 times, to no avail.

What other options exist to force the phone to reboot, other than waiting for the power to exhaust itself completely after several hours?

Answer (score 4):

Press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Volume Down buttons for at least ten seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

Comment: You might also include a link to the relevant docs: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201412

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it restarted.

I pressed the home button first, for about 3 seconds by itself, then I came in afterward with a press of the power button, and it restarted within 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you were in DFU mode.  If you hold on to home and power then just hold home, it goes past the hard reset and into dev mode.  To get out of it, you can either connect to itunes and force a reset or press home and power for 3 seconds only.  That should get you out of it...

I can't tell you how many times I had this issue.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

let it die and then recharge it it will basically do a hard reset.